# For SEO URLs via .htaccess do extensions need to be 301'd as well?

Tags: url-rewriting, seo, http-status-code-301

After researching, I have come to some conclusions for utilizing SEO URLs.  For semi-static `.php` based sites that have file names such as `index.php`, `about.php`, `contact.php` etc I am using htaccess `mod_rewrite` rules so that for example '`www.mysite.com/about`' can be used in place of '`www.mysite.com/about.php`'.  In such cases, all of my menus and links are then pointing at the SEO URL.

What I have found out though, is that even though nothing in my site references the `.php` extensions, if I enter them directly, they stick.  So, I can get to the about page using `/about` or `/about.php`, and each will show as entered.  It seems reading through posts here that this is a common issue.

My question is, does this matter?  If nothing in my site references the `.php` extensions in a link or menu, do i need to be worried about duplicate content??

I was told I need to add something in htaccess like:

```
redirect 301 /about.php http://www.mysite.com/about
```

for each page to eliminate the possibility but I don't understand if this is really an issue in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Questions:
Q1. "Does this matter"?
Answer: Not if you've never exposed the .php URLs before. If you have, then the answer changes to "yes".

Q2. What .htaccess?
Answer:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Note. My .htaccess 'foo' is not strong, I wouldn't be surprised if someone offers a more elegant solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks on both answers... you know, I tried that htaccess combination, but for some reason it still does not 'remove' the .php .... in fact so far in testing the 'redirect 301...' is the only thing I have been able to get it to physically remove that extension if it is typed directly.  Can that 'redirect 301...' be applied in a universal manner instead of per page?

Answer (score 0):

Your URLs are SEO friendly if there are some keywords in it that relate to the content and if they are not overly dynamic in a sense that Google Bot can interpret them (take a look at the Google Webmastertools and [read this](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=76329)).

So I would not worry about "mysite.com/about" versus "mysite.com/about.php". I would rather watch out to avoid [duplicate content](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66359) if you want to change the URLs.

Here are some more links for further reference:

- [Making Website URLs SEO Friendly and Pretty](http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/making-website-urls-seo-friendly-and-pretty)
- [Some articles and advice on Duplicate Content](http://www.seomoz.org/pages/search_results?q=duplicate%20content)

Comment: Thanks for this, I will check the links on a break later today. You are right, my reference to 'SEO url' was not really accurate in this case, but it is the end goal ;-)